# vector capacity shows 0 even though it is reserved

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class that has a vector as one of member variables. Within the constructor, the vector capacity is reserved (class VecUser uses 'Test' object):

```
class Test {
public:  
  Test(uint32_t size) {
    this->v.reserve(size);
    std::cout << v.capacity() << std::endl; // this prints 'size'
  }
  vector<uint32_t>& getV() { return v; }
private:
  vector<uint32_t> v;
};

class VecUser {
public:
  VecUser() {}
private:
  void func() {
    Test* test = new Test(32); // This prints '32' 

    vector<uint32_t> v = test->getV();
    std::cout << v.capacity() << std::endl; // This prints '0'
  }
};
```

I think that the `cout` in the `func()` function has to print '32', not '0'.

But, after running it, it prints 0.

Why the reserved vector shows its capacity is 0?

Comment: The `v` in `func()` is a copy of the `v` from `Test`

Comment: You're making a copy of `test->getV()`. Change `v = test->getV()` to `vec<uint32_t> &v = test->getV()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This here

```
vector<uint32_t> v = test->getV();
```

Makes a copy. `v` isn't actually a reference, so even though you return one, it has to make a copy anyway. Because it is a copy, it doesn't need that same amount of reserved space. If you actually get the reference instead like this:

```
vector<uint32_t> &v = test->getV();
```

The output is `32` both times.

Comment: Does not the first case 'move' the original vector?

Comment: @sungjuncho: Absolutely not. That would have been an horrendous breaking change in the language. This is a good answer. +1..

Answer (score 7):

The *copy-initialized* `v` following `vector<uint32_t> v = test->getV();` is a *value copy* of `test->getV()`.

The C++ standard does not require the copying of the source vector's capacity following *copy initialization*, so the capacity of `v` is allowed to be any value subject to it being greater than or equal to the number of elements.

Comment: Indeed this is the basis of the old "shrink to size" trick (before we had `shrink_to_fit`, which is also non-binding)